# Calculation of the cumulative points before the event/game

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I would like to cumulate the points of several football clubs for each one for a match day.

I have created a sample dataset to explain the problem:

```
t <- data.frame(Heim = c("A", "B", "B", "D", "C", "A", "C", "D", "A", "B", "B", "D", "C", "A", "C", "D"), 
                Auswärts = c("C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "B", "D", "A", "B"),
                Ergebnis= c("S", "U", "N", "N", "S", "S", "N", "U", "N", "S", "N", "U", "S", "S", "U", "U"),
                Round = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                Saison = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

My idea was for each club (in the origin data set more than 4) a separate column with the score and a cummulated column to it.

So something like this:

```
t$A_Points <- ifelse(t$Heim =="A" & t$Ergebnis =="S", 3, 0)
t$A_Points  <- ifelse(t$Heim =="A" & t$Ergebnis =="U", 1, t$A_Points )
t$A_Points  <- ifelse(t$Auswärts =="A" & t$Ergebnis =="U", 1, t$A_Points )
t$A_Points  <- ifelse(t$Auswärts =="A" & t$Ergebnis =="N", 3, t$A_Points )
t$A_Points  <- ifelse(t$Auswärts !="A" & t$Heim !="A", NA, t$A_Points)
t$A<- ifelse(t$A_Points  == "NA", 0, 1)

t<- t %>% 
  arrange(Saison,Round,A) %>%
  group_by(Saison, A) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(A_Points))
```

Unfortunately, it is very time and space-consuming even for 4 clubs...
Also, I would like to have the sum of the points of the matches without the result of the current matchday.

The optimal result for me would be following:

```
Heim  Auswärts Ergebnis Round Saison    Points_Heim Points_Auswärts 
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A     C        S            1      1        0       0
 2 B     D        U            1      1        0       0
 3 B     A        N            2      1        1       3
 4 D     C        N            2      1        1       0
 5 A     D        S            3      1        6       1          
 6 C     B        S            3      1        3       1
 7 C     A        N            4      1        6       9
 8 D     B        U            4      1        1       1
 9 A     C        N            1      2        0       0
10 B     D        S            1      2        0       0
11 B     A        N            2      2        3       0
12 D     C        U            2      2        0       3
13 A     D        S            3      2        3       1
14 C     B        S            3      2        4       3
15 C     A        U            4      2        7       3    
16 D     B        U            4      2        1       3
```

I would be very happy about an idea for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the shortest solution. But I would do

```
t <- t %>% 
  group_by(Saison) %>%
  mutate(Heim_Points_Veränderung = case_when(Ergebnis == "S" ~ 3,
                                             Ergebnis == "U" ~ 1,
                                             Ergebnis == "N" ~ 0),
         Auswärts_Points_Veränderung = case_when(Ergebnis == "S" ~ 0,
                                                 Ergebnis == "U" ~ 1,
                                                 Ergebnis == "N" ~ 3),
         Points_Heim = 0,
         Points_Auswärts = 0)

for (i in unique(union(t$Heim, t$Auswärts))){
  t <- t %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(paste0(i,"_points")) := if_else(Heim == i, Heim_Points_Veränderung, 0),
           !!sym(paste0(i,"_points")) := if_else(Auswärts == i, Auswärts_Points_Veränderung, !!sym(paste0(i,"_points"))),
           !!sym(paste0(i,"_cumsum")) := cumsum(lag(!!sym(paste0(i,"_points")), default=0)),
           Points_Heim = if_else(Heim == i, !!sym(paste0(i,"_cumsum")), Points_Heim),
           Points_Auswärts = if_else(Auswärts == i, !!sym(paste0(i,"_cumsum")), Points_Auswärts))
}

t <- t %>%
  select(Heim, Auswärts, Ergebnis, Round, Saison, Points_Heim, Points_Auswärts)
```

Output

```
> t
# A tibble: 16 x 7
# Groups:   Saison [2]
   Heim  Auswärts Ergebnis Round Saison Points_Heim Points_Auswärts
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 A     C        S            1      1           0               0
 2 B     D        U            1      1           0               0
 3 B     A        N            2      1           1               3
 4 D     C        N            2      1           1               0
 5 C     B        S            3      1           3               1
 6 A     D        S            3      1           6               1
 7 C     A        N            4      1           6               9
 8 D     B        U            4      1           1               1
 9 A     C        N            1      2           0               0
10 B     D        S            1      2           0               0
11 B     A        N            2      2           3               0
12 D     C        U            2      2           0               3
13 C     B        S            3      2           4               3
14 A     D        S            3      2           3               1
15 C     A        U            4      2           7               6
16 D     B        U            4      2           1               3
```

This solution should adapt to any number of clubs. Briefly, I store the possible change in points in Heim/Auswärts_Points_Veränderung using `case_when` (easier than a lot of `ifelse`) so I can create a column of points change for each club (running a `for` loop on all the clubs). This allows me to do a `cumsum` like you using `lag` to make sure the cumsum is updated 1 row later (to display the cumulative points before the match and not after), which I enter in the Points_Heim/Auswärts column only when the club is displayed in the Heim/Auswärts columns. The key to my solution is to use `!!sym` to feed dynamic variable names to `mutate` (note the assignment with `:=`) inside the `for` loop.

Comment: You're welcome =) May I suggest not using `t` as an object name in the future, since there is a function with the same name (to transpose)